# MariaDB Update Column Values Based on Another Column's Value

Tags: mariadb

I have a column 'StormID' 'Basin' which both hold text based values.

`StormID   Basin
EP012018   NEP
EP022018   NEP
CP012018   NEP` <--  I want this value to change to NCP if the first 2 characters are 'CP' in the StormID column.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Regards,
Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`left()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/left/) to get the first *n* characters of a string.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET basin = 'NCP'
       WHERE left(stormid, 2) = 'CP';
```

Comment: knahT you very much  :)